# How do I decipher this perl statement $params->{$1}{'Kx'} = $2

Tags: hash

Iam trying to decipher the intent perl code given below:

```perl
sub get_input_params($) {
    my ($file) = @_;
    my $params = {};
    open(IN, $file) or die "Input file not found";
    while(<IN>)
    {
    if(/^\s*JOINT (\d{4}) (.{7})(.{7})(.{7})(.{7})(.{7})(.{7}) ELASTIC?\s*$/i)
    {
        $params->{$1}{'Kx'} = $2;
        $params->{$1}{'Ky'} = $3;
        $params->{$1}{'Kz'} = $4;
        $params->{$1}{'Txx'} = $5;
        $params->{$1}{'Tyy'} = $6;
        $params->{$1}{'Tzz'} = $7;
    }
    }
    close(IN);

    $params;
};
```

## In particular Iam stuck at this :

```
$params->{$1}{'Kx'} = $2;
```

Can someone give a source for getting this clarified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose the current line of the file is

```
JOIN 1234 uuuuuuuvvvvvvvwwwwwwwxxxxxxxyyyyyyyzzzzzzz ELASTIC ...
      $1     $2     $3      $4    $5    $6     $7
```

the contents after `ELASTIC` being irrelevant.

The capture groups are referred to by number, as shown above.

`$params` is a hash reference, with `$1` being used as a key mapped to *another* hash with keys `Kx`, `Ky`, etc. Using the example line above, the following assignments would be made

```
$params->{1234}{Kx} = "uuuuuuu"
$params->{1234}{Ky} = "vvvvvvv"
$params->{1234}{Kz} = "wwwwwww"
$params->{1234}{Txx} = "xxxxxxx"
$params->{1234}{Tyy} = "yyyyyyy"
$params->{1234}{Tzz} = "zzzzzzz"
```